# How to make transaction using private key and address using web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, raw-transaction, web3j, java

I have a private key and address . Is it possible to make transaction with these parameter using web3j.

Answer (score 3):

```
Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(""));
    Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("privateKey");
    BigInteger nonce = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(credentials.getAddress(), DefaultBlockParameterName.PENDING).sendAsync().get().getTransactionCount();
    BigInteger gasPrice = web3j.ethGasPrice().sendAsync().get().getGasPrice();
    RawTransaction rawTransaction = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, gasPrice, Constants.ETH_GAS_LIMIT, "address", Convert.toWei("amount", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigIntegerExact());
    EthSendTransaction response = web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(Numeric.toHexString(TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, credentials))).send();
    String hash = response.getTransactionHash();
```

Comment: just use this method and put your parameters on the place of the strings.

Comment: Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(""));
  TransactionReceipt receipt = Transfer.sendFunds(web3j, Credentials.create("privateKey"), "toAddress", new BigDecimal("amount"), Convert.Unit.ETHER).sendAsync().get();
  System.err.println(receipt.getTransactionHash());

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send custom tokens as the contract owner, check out my answer here: [Send Custom ERC20 Tokens from one Address to another](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29607/send-custom-erc20-tokens-from-one-address-to-another/41186#41186)

If you want to send tokens on behalf of another user, the idea is similiar.

First retrieve user's credentials from the privatekey , then do transaction.

```
Credentials getUserInfo (String privateKeyInHex){

    BigInteger privateKeyInBT = new BigInteger(privateKeyInHex, 16);

    ECKeyPair aPair = ECKeyPair.create(privateKeyInBT);
    Credentials aCredential = Credentials.create(aPair);

    return aCredential;
}
```

send tokens:

```
process(){
    ... 

    Credentials newUser =  getUserInfo(privateKeyInHex);

    TransactionReceiptProcessor transactionReceiptProcessor = new NoOpProcessor(web3);
    TransactionManager transactionManager = new RawTransactionManager(
                            web3, newUser, ChainId.MAINNET, transactionReceiptProcessor);
                    //if testing, use ChainId.ROPSTEN
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to send transaction. Use web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:'0xaddress', 
from:'0xaddress',
value:web3.toWei(.033,'ether'),gas:30000})

Comment: Question is about `web3j` not `web3js`

Comment: are you using Ethereum wallet?

Comment: I have no wallet file. I have only ethereum private key and address