# Send ERC-20 token using Web3j

Tags: web3j

What is the best way to get balance and send ERC-20 token using web3j?

Comment: Did you try anything? There are a few similar questions answered already https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29607/send-custom-erc20-tokens-from-one-address-to-another.

Comment: Ivan my man the community is awaiting your return can you please answer me in the discord