# Trouble implementing ERC20 payment service in android application

Tags: web3j, java, android

I have been following this tutorial (https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/a-primer-to-ethereum-token-development-using-java-and-web3j-52b24cc6c403) but seem to keep running into errors when it comes to creating a java wrapper for the erc20 contract,

i have a few questions but have no one to consult so i am trying my luck here, is the "web3j truffle generate" still working? i keep getting web3j cli errors, or is there a different way for going about generating a wrapper class?

I cant seem to find any tutorials on using erc20 with android so I havent anything else to compare too, i did see this ([Send Custom ERC20 Tokens from one Address to another](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29607/send-custom-erc20-tokens-from-one-address-to-another)) but couldnt really get anywhere with it,

anyone have any success implementing a payment service in an android app that allows a user to pay using a utility token?

Any help trying to implement this feature would be greatly appreciated